# Convert UTC to EST timezone

Tags: java

I have to convert `UTC` timestamp data to `EST` timezone. Below code is working fine when timezone difference is -`5Hrs` but when I give `UTC` time like - `2018-04-15T21:27:31.000Z` then it outputs as `2018-04-15 16:27:31 -0500` which is not correct. Output should be `2018-04-15 17:27:31 -0400`. It always subtract -`5hrs`.

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateFormat estFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
estFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

try {
    String date1 = estFormat.format(utcFormat.parse("2018-04-15T21:27:31.000Z"));

    System.out.println("est time : "+date1);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you taking care of daylight saving

Comment: Sorry Vinay, I did not get your point. I have above code where I am setting timezones.

Comment: EST will not take care of day light savings while EDT is supposed to take care of day light savings

Comment: 21-5h is 16.... seams correct to me.

Comment: Just cheked and EST is -5h.

Comment: EST is a fixed timezone. You have to choose between EST and EDT depending on time of year. If you are on Linux system, you can use EST5EDT timezone which automatically switches between EST and EDT depending on whether DST is in play or not.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to expect the time zone shorthand named "EST" to obey the daylight saving time change rules. It doesn't. "EST" is the name for a time zone which is GMT-5 at any time of the year.

To get time zone definitions that obey daylight saving time rules as expected, you'll be better off using the name of the main cities that use these time zones.

In your case, try "America/New_York"